# Ajax.Actionlink, how to get the form data to the controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**View**

`<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Create", "Create", ViewData.Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })%>`

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", ViewData.Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod ="POST" }))
   {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Title">Title:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Name")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Description">Description:</label>
            <%= Html.TextArea("ContactNo")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*")%>
        </p>           

    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Controller

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer info)
    {
       //INFO IS NULL???
       //WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the model object.  This argument expects the route values such as an ID.

if you pass in  `Ajax.ActionLink("Create", "Create", new { id=23 }, ....`

it will create `/create/23`.